# Unable to get linq query data in the async ActionResult with await and task, Error: await can't be used with async method

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

How to get the LINQ query data in the `Task<IHttpActionResult>` return type? I have stored the data in `var ponddata` variable. How to return the data in the `Task<IHttpActionResult>` action method? I'm getting this error at `return Ok` statement:

> Error CS1061  'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'IQueryable<>' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllData(string user)
{
    using (smartpondEntities entities = new smartpondEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var ponddata = from pond in entities.ponds
                join customerdevice in entities.CustomerDevices on pond.imei equals customerdevice.imei
                join userdata in entities.Users on customerdevice.CustomerId equals userdata.CustomerId
                where userdata.Username == "user1"
                select new { temperature = pond.temp, Imei = pond.imei, timestamp = pond.timestatmp };
            return Ok(await ponddata);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("Sorry Error Found!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked what the exception message is?

Comment: Use the `async` keyword, and ideally `await` something

Comment: error - Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: decimal? temperature, string Imei, DateTime? timestamp>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: decimal? temperature, string Imei, DateTime? timestamp>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SmartPondAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler returns the `Task` for you when you use the *async and await pattern*, (or more precisely) when you decorate your method with the `async` keyword

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllData(string user)
```

To take advantage of the pattern, you commonly `await` something in these methods.